# Unexpected hits being sent to a GA360 property

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

I recently got to work on a GA360 property, and came to know that there's a weird issue going on with it.

Basically, the company had created a custom dimension to record the GTM container version and ID for whichever container was currently live. For e.g., if the current container ID is XYZ and version is 23, then the dimension would record "XYZ version 23".

Then they created a custom report, showing this dimension and the corresponding number of hits.

Now coming to the issue, since the past few months, they've been seeing hits coming from both live AND older versions of the same container. The older versions are not supposed to be live but somehow they still show up in the reports.

Purely based on the description, can anyone share their suggestions as to what might have gone wrong?

EDIT: It is an app property.

Comment: Are the interactions with previous versions recent or do they refer to past dates in the reports?

Comment: Basically every internal network that runs its incoming web traffic through a proxy can choose to cache the gtm.js file indefinitely, and since all your variables including the version number are bundled in there, all pages loaded from that network would use the old container.

Comment: @Michele The interactions are recent. If I were to open that custom report with a date range of this week, it would still show hits coming from containers that were live month ago. Also, I forgot to mention in the original description, this is an App property. Also, they use a lot of webviews in it.

Comment: @Eike Can this happen in an app property as well? I forgot to mention that its an app property in the original description, sorry for that. Also, the app uses a lot of webviews, so would that factor into the equation?